# Count input length without spaces, periods, or commas, can someone help here?

Tags: python

[image: obnoxious screenshot]

Given a line of text as input, output the number of characters excluding spaces, periods, or commas.

Ex: If the input is:  `Listen, Mr. Jones, calm down.` the output is:  `21`

Note: Account for all characters that aren't spaces, periods, or commas (Ex: "r", "2", "!").

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have added a picture

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In the most simple terms all you have to do is create a character filter, and sum all the characters that are not in the filter. `sum` is used because using `len` would also require a `join` and a condition. We can save some processing by not trying to reformat the string.

```
f = ' .,'    #character filter

length = sum(not c in f for c in input())
```

---

`len` method for comparison

```
f = ' .,'    #character filter
t = input()

length = len("".join(c for c in t if not c in f))
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

```py
print(len(string.replace(',','').replace(' ','').replace('.','')))
```

Where `string` is your input string.

Comment: Your method is not scalable. What if they needed to add 4 more characters to omit? Are you going to keep chaining replace statements to infinity?

Comment: No, I agree @OneMadGypsy it's not scalable, and it wasn't really meant to be. The OP asked a specific question related to what looked like a stock high-school-coding-class problem, which asks to count a number of characters in a given string, specifically stating the set of characters to exclude is just commas, periods and spaces. Given this constraint, it's perfectly acceptable to chain the replace statements as a solution to this problem. I totally agree that in the real world, and especially when scalability is desireable, you want to, and indeed should, use a regex based solution.

Comment: Furthermore, in this era of TDD and BDD driven development, making the test pass comes first, and tidy code looks after itself. If this where a real world solution, as an initial draft its fine... if, later on, it gets revisited because the set of excluded characters has now grown, refactoring happens. Build for the now is cheaper in the long run than building for the future. Took me a long while to embrace this concept - but it is true. Trying to code for a requirement that a customer MIGHT need in six months time is more expensive than doing it IN six months time when we KNOW the requirement

Comment: If you wrote code like that for me, I would immediately fire you. I understand what you are saying, but there are lines for your argument, and I opine that your answer is on the wrong side of the line. Keep in mind, you are teaching someone that doesn't even know how to ignore characters that your way is some kind of way legitimate. No R&D was wasted on my answer.

Comment: It's a trivial question, so we sound silly right now - but I do see the point & wasn't in disagreement with your statement. Your point teaching the right way hasn't gone unnoticed, either. I was just introducing the concept of delivering in the shortest time. In this case, building a scalable regex is using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. It took me ~ten seconds to write a line of not-very-pretty-code, instead of ~30 mins to build/test a regex. Yes its neat, pretty and scaleable - do that WHEN the customer wants it, not before - customer might never want it, yet we increased R&D budget 60-fold.

Answer (score -1):

```
user_text = input()
chars_to_remove = ' ,.'
char_count = 0
for character in user_text:
    if character not in chars_to_remove:
        char_count += 1
print(char_count)
```